# Give focus to Internet Explorer object created through C#

Tags: c#, embed

I'm having some problems with the control of IE through C#.
I have almost everything managed.
But I can't seem to set the focus to opened explorer.
When I'm in VS 2010 it works, but this isn't the case when I run the exe file directly.

```
using SHDocVw;
.

<code>

.
InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorer();
IWebBrowserApp wb = (IWebBrowserApp)ie;
.

<code>

.   
wb.Visible = true;
wb.Document.focus();
```

I mean that `wb.Document.focus();` would give focus to IE, but that dosen't work.
Have also tried with `eb.Document.focus();`
Anyone have a sugestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the ie.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument then set the focus.

```
//Like so
InternetExplorer ie = new InternetExplorer();
((mshtml.HTMLDocument)ie.Document).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not reliable. The reliable solution is with API (my discovery :-) ) :

vb:

```
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long

Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass

ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer : Application.DoEvents()



'the reliable focus:

ShowWindow(ie.HWND, 0) : ShowWindow(ie.HWND, 1)
```

Comment: Looks like the question is seeking C#. You should probably update your answer and add [code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).